# Basic questions about path syntax in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have questions about the syntax of this Cypher query:

```
MATCH (tom:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(tomHanksMovies)
RETURN tom, tomHanksMovies
```

I swear I've seen some paths that have two dashes, as in `--[:ACTED_IN]`. What is the difference between two and one dash?

The relationship in the `MATCH` pattern is: `[:ACTED_IN]`. I think it's safe to say that the key is missing because there is no need for an identifier.

By extension, then why doesn't `(tomHanksMovies)` need to be written to explicitly show that it *is* basically just an identifier, as in `(tomHanksMovies:)`? Or is it not an identifier? I've read it called a variable as well. What's the correct terminology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have seen Cypher patterns like this: `(a)-->(b)`, but never `(a)--[:ACTED_IN]->(b)`, as the latter is not legal. The `--` syntax just means that there is a relationship, but the relationship type does not matter (and you don't need to use any relationship properties).

You indicate an identifier as the first string after the `(` for a node or `[` for a relationship, as long as the string does not start with a `:` or `{` character. The `:` character is used before a *node label* or *relationship type*. The `{` and `}` characters are used enclose property name/value pairs.

An `identifier` is referred to that way in the neo4j documentation, so that is the preferred name. However, people often use `variable` as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing up all these little annoying questions I had!

Comment: But...what's the reasoning behind `[:ACTED_IN]` and not just `[ACTED_IN]`?